# How can I add an error statement in a loop if the user entered letters instead of numbers

Tags: java, loops, random, error-handling

How can I add an error statement in a loop if the user entered letters instead of numbers but the program should continue

```
package sample;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int playerGuess;
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
        int numberOfAttempts = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Guess a number from 1 to 50: ");
            playerGuess = scan.nextInt();
            numberOfAttempts++;

            if (playerGuess == randomNum) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations! The number was: " + randomNum);
                System.out.println("You got it in " + numberOfAttempts + " attempts.");
                break;
            }
            else if (randomNum > playerGuess) {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too low. Try again.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Your guess is too high. Try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My program works fine but I forgot how to add an error statement in a loop. Can someone help me where and how to add an error statement when the user entered letters instead of numbers? Thank you in advance! :)))**

Comment: Declare the `playerguess` and initialize to = 0. Use variable as the condition  '(playerGuess == 0)` for your `while` loop. Place the `playerGuess = scan.nextInt();` line of code within a `try/catch` block situation. Place all your other code within the `try` code block and at the end add `playerGuess = 0;`. Within the `catch` block, inform the User of the error and make the `playerGuess` variable = 0. Also consume the newline character from the ENTER key hit ('scan.nextLine();'). If you can't remember how...you should by now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for errors using try and catch blocks. All you have to do is wrap the error-prone code in a try block and check for a SPECIFIC exception and handle it. Don't just leave the catch empty, it is a bad practice.
You could do it this way, but I would recommend using if statements to check if your input contains numbers